# How to create IOS apk using cordova (angular js web)

Tags: angular, cordova, command-line

I am using cordova commands to create ios apk ,corodva build failed due to Xcodebuild was not found.

Xcodebuild is necessary for windows 10?

I was created android apk using cordova.Its working fine.
pls help me.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need Xcode to build apps for iOS and therefore a Mac computer. Please see this guide for more details. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Comment: I m using cordova & creating apk through command line . Same thing  i was implemented using cordova & command line (adnroid & IOS Apk).

So Pls tell us Using cordova how to create apk.
Cordova provided build IOS option & add ios platform .

Comment: To build for Android, you need Android Studio which you probably have on Windows but for iOS you need Xcode on Mac. That's why the error you said occurred.

Comment: I have windows  10 OS , don't have Mac System. then How to create ios  apk using cordova.
Can I install Xcode on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Like rgiller said, you can't build ios app without Mac.

But if you can't buy a Mac or just don't want to buy it you can use phonegap build service allow you to build apk and ipa with the same process.

Unfortunately for build and deploy and IPA (it's the APK but for Apple) you need a Apple dev account and a P12 file AND mobileprovision.

P12 and mobileprovision should be generate from a Mac but you can rent it with service like https://www.macincloud.com/

For more information about phonegap : http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/